# How can I disable the screenshot sound on iPad?

Tags: audio, ios, screen-capture, ipad

How to get rid of the screenshot sound on iPad? (iOS 7)
I have tried muting the iPad but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you switched the mute button to off? Or have you just set the volume to 0?

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Settings*

You will get a search box right on top of the left corner of the ipad as you sweep from downwards

Search for "lock sounds"

You will get ringer and alerts turn that to zero

It's done

Answer (score 1):

If your device is jailbroken you can rename the sound file.

```
mv /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter-off.caf
```

Note:

- The file will be restored on an iOS update.
- The same file is used for the camera shutter sound, so renaming it will remove the sound from the camera shutter.

Comment: No,it is not jailbroken.